# Grails easyb plugin source code

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I am looking to check-out grails easy plugin source code .But I could not find out complete source code .Any help would be highly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

If your looking for the easyb *plugin* source, and *not* the easyb source code, it would be located in the following location if you've installed it in your project:

> ${userHome}/.grails/${grailsVersion}/projects/${project}/plugins/easyb-2.0.5